# Android SDK BLE Support on Galaxy Tab 2 (Android 4.2.2)

Tags: android, sdk, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I need to simply discover a BLE device presence and its signal strenght. 
I know Galaxy Tab 2 has just Bluetooth 3.0 chipset in fact, my android sdk code doesn't find any BLE device.

Is it possibile to get a workaround to simply check the BLE presence (force chipset to use BT 4.0, use different discovering code,etc.) ? I don't need any further connection, pairing and so on..
Please Help.

Comment: In case you can discover LE devices in pairing-ready mode at the same time with regular bluetooth devices, guess you can somehow get to know if device is supports LE or LE-only

Comment: No, BLE and legacy bluetooth signaling are quite different. *If* your device does not have a BLE-compatible chipset you will not be able to detect BLE devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can now discover a BLE devices using the Samsung BLE SKD for Android 4.2, 4.2.1 and 4.2.2. but the BLE beacons are discoverable just if they are turned on. If they are in deep sleep mode, my application doesn't find them. Is it possibile to wake up these BLE devices (beacons)? I need just their presence and signal strenght. Thank you so much!!!